# 'No WebView found' - Hybrid app - protractor - iPad real device

Tags: ios, protractor, appium, appium-ios

I'm trying to run my protractor scripts on Web, Android and iOS devices. In Web and Android it is working fine but getting 'No WebView found' error while trying to run on iOS device.

Steps followed:
1. Run **ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c null:27753,:27753-27853**

```
Listing devices on :27753
Connected :27755 to iPad (**************)
```

2. Started **Appium** server

> [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.8.0
>       [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

3. Run **Protractor iOSConfig.js**

> [iOS] Could not find any webviews yet, refreshing/retrying
>       [debug] [iOS] Retrieving contexts and views
>       [debug] [iOS] Selecting by url: false 
>       [debug] [RemoteDebugger] Getting WebKitRemoteDebugger pageArray: localhost, 27755
>       [debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending request to: http://localhost:27755/json
>       [debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page element JSON: []
>       [debug] [iOS] No web frames found.

Any inputs will be welcome as developers have already declared it as an hybrid application.

Comment: try to open URL in safari first on mobile

Comment: you can also inspect element and debug webView on mobile

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich I didn't get your comment. Can you please elaborate more on this.

Comment: I was suggesting that you can test that your URL is working by opening it in safari application.

Comment: And an other suggestion is you can debug webView using xCode.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich The URL is opening fine on Safari but issue is coming while automating the app version on iPad real device.